# ValueType ref return from List or Dictionary, Workarounds?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, ref

I'm working in a new C# codebase where they use structs heavily.  I've done a lot of C# but not too much with structs.  (I always tried to avoid them after reading this type of stuff: [Why are mutable structs “evil”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil))

Most of the issues that I have run into are from accidentally copying a struct when I really want to get a reference to an existing struct.  Functions that return ref and using ref to get values out of arrays of structs are very useful for avoiding copying.

But what is a good solution for storing structs in a list or dictionary and getting a reference out of those?  There appears to be no equivalent of a ref return for arrays.  Am I missing a way to do this?

As a workaround, I have taken to creating a container class for structs like in the code below.  Is there any alternative?  Also, is there some generic value type wrapper class built into C# that I should be using for each of these instead of defining my own?  Some sort of IValueTypeWrapperForContainers?

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public int foo;
}

class MyClass
{
    public MyStruct ms;
    public MyClass()
    {
        ms = new MyStruct();
        ms.foo = 42;
    }
}
```

This does not change the value of 42 because ms1 is a copy of the struct:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, MyStruct> timeStructMap = new Dictionary<DateTime, MyStruct>();
MyStruct ms = new MyStruct();
timeStructMap.Add(DateTime.Today, ms);

var ms1 = timeStructMap[DateTime.Today];
ms1.foo = 43;
```

This does what I want instead.

```
Dictionary<DateTime, MyClass> timeClassMap = new Dictionary<DateTime, MyClass>();
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
timeClassMap.Add(DateTime.Today, mc);

var mc1 = timeClassMap[DateTime.Today];
mc1.ms.foo = 43;
```

Comment: It *is* kinda sorta possible to get the `ref T` of an element out of a `List<T>` - via some framework utility methods; however, it generally isn't recommended as it gets into a mess if/when the list gets mutated and the backing array gets swapped. There isn't a general purpose solution to this, but to be fair: it is very rarely needed. In almost all cases, people are better off using `readonly struct` for immutable data, or `class` for mutable. There are valid scenarios for ignoring this advice, but they're niche; and in that niche: you have to accept the limitations